# AS3 Fullscreen air Application looses focus

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air, keyboard, kiosk

I'm currently building a kiosk program with as3+airkinect so the whole interface is built up with the Kinect and one external Button which is a keyboard input. Somehow the .exe program I've built looses the focus of the window after about one hour, which has the effect that the keyboard listener stops listening. I can detect a `Event.DEACTIVATE`, how can i make shure the keyboard listener always works?

Comment: please post the relevant code that you already have, and what you tried with which results

Comment: You should try to find the reason in the underlying system. You cannot just obtain the focus to your application back from inside of your application.